# dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to run a keypad software thing but whenever i try to run it it says

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTTNSt3__114basic_ifstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/nd_admin/Downloads/setting/./Sayo_CLI_Mac_X64 (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

(if it helps this software is supposed to give out an online link with all the keypad drivers and stuff)

I've tried finding the dylib inside the usr file, but it just inputs unreadable characters

Comment: You generally want to give enough information to duplicate the problem/error message you are getting. If you don't say waht the software is and where/how to get it, it's extremely unlikely you'll get a useful answer here.

Comment: the software is from https://osu.sayobot.cn/download/